# IPSec IKEv2 on pfSense: "parsed INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]"

Tags: vpn, ipsec, ikev2

I am trying to setup an IPSec IKEv2 VPN Network on a pfSense. The pfsense is situated directly behind the modem. I connect to it by a static IP address. There is no double NAT. I followed this tutorial:

[netgate IKEv2 Tutorial](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/recipes/ipsec-mobile-ikev2-eap-mschapv2.html)

The connection doesn't work. The log on the pfSense for an android trying to connect to the firewall:

```
    Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <1> received packet: from 109.42.113.240[49837] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (650 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <1> parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> looking for an IKEv2 config for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...109.42.113.240
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> candidate: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...0.0.0.0/0, ::/0, prio 1052
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> found matching ike config: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 with prio 1052
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <1> 109.42.113.240 is initiating an IKE_SA
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <1> IKE_SA (unnamed)[1] state change: CREATED => CONNECTING
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> selecting proposal:
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> proposal matches
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> received proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_256/AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048_256/ECP_384/ECP_256/MODP_2048/MODP_1536, IKE:AES_GCM_16_256/AES_GCM_16_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048_256/ECP_384/ECP_256/MODP_2048/MODP_1536
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> configured proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <1> received supported signature hash algorithms: sha256 sha384 sha512
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <1> remote host is behind NAT
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <1> DH group MODP_2048_256 unacceptable, requesting MODP_2048
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <1> generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <1> sending packet: from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 109.42.113.240[49837] (38 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <1> IKE_SA (unnamed)[1] state change: CONNECTING => DESTROYING
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <2> received packet: from 109.42.113.240[49837] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] (650 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <2> parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> looking for an IKEv2 config for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...109.42.113.240
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> candidate: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...0.0.0.0/0, ::/0, prio 1052
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> found matching ike config: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 with prio 1052
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <2> 109.42.113.240 is initiating an IKE_SA
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <2> IKE_SA (unnamed)[2] state change: CREATED => CONNECTING
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> selecting proposal:
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> proposal matches
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> received proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_256/AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048/MODP_2048_256/ECP_384/ECP_256/MODP_1536, IKE:AES_GCM_16_256/AES_GCM_16_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_512/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_384/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048/MODP_2048_256/ECP_384/ECP_256/MODP_1536
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> configured proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> received supported signature hash algorithms: sha256 sha384 sha512
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <2> remote host is behind NAT
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> sending supported signature hash algorithms: sha256 sha384 sha512 identity
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <2> sending cert request for "CN=CApfSense, C=DE, ST=SH, L=Kiel"
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <2> generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) CERTREQ N(HASH_ALG) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <2> sending packet: from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[500] to 109.42.113.240[49837] (489 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <2> received packet: from 109.42.113.240[58932] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] (352 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <2> parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi CPRQ(ADDR DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_6_ADDR) N(ADD_6_ADDR) N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> looking for peer configs matching xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[%any]...109.42.113.240[mobile]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <2> candidate "con-mobile", match: 1/1/1052 (me/other/ike)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[CFG] <con-mobile|2> selected peer config 'con-mobile'
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> initiating EAP_IDENTITY method (id 0x00)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> processing INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS attribute
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> processing INTERNAL_IP4_DNS attribute
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> peer supports MOBIKE
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> got additional MOBIKE peer address: 2a00:20:7001:d583:88d0:45b0:8275:ddf7
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> got additional MOBIKE peer address: 2a00:20:70ce:7c05:b6b3:d5fb:adc5:c902
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> authentication of 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (myself) with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_256 successful
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> sending end entity cert "CN=pfSense, C=DE, ST=SH, L=Kiel"
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <con-mobile|2> generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <con-mobile|2> sending packet: from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] to 109.42.113.240[58932] (1472 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <con-mobile|2> received packet: from 109.42.113.240[58932] to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] (80 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <con-mobile|2> parsed INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <con-mobile|2> generating INFORMATIONAL response 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[NET] <con-mobile|2> sending packet: from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx[4500] to 109.42.113.240[58932] (80 bytes)
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[IKE] <con-mobile|2> IKE_SA con-mobile[2] state change: CONNECTING => DESTROYING
```

The issue seems to be in these lines:

```
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <con-mobile|2> parsed INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Sep 6 07:59:03  charon  97494   07[ENC] <con-mobile|2> generating INFORMATIONAL response 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
```

What does it mean and where should I look for setup mistakes? Apparently it is an authentification issue. Is there something wrong with the certificates? What else could be the reason? (The certificates are installed on my phone as well of course) I also tried to connect with a windows client which also failed.

It looks like that the key exchange first fails ("generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]") and then succeeds at the second attempt. Why?

The RFC5996 states: *"All errors that occur in an IKE_AUTH exchange, causing the authentication to fail for whatever reason (invalid shared secret, invalid ID, untrusted certificate issuer, revoked or expired certificate, etc.)  SHOULD result in an AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notification."*

What is meant by ID and shared secret?

```
 [if] => mvneta0.4092
                [descr] => OPT
                [switchif] => switch0.port1
            )

        [opt2] => Array
            (
                [descr] => MANAGEMENT
                [if] => mvneta0.5
                [enable] =>
                [ipaddr] => 10.168.5.1
                [subnet] => 24
                [spoofmac] =>
            )

        [opt3] => Array
            (
                [descr] => IOT
                [if] => mvneta0.10
                [enable] =>
                [ipaddr] => 10.168.10.1
                [subnet] => 24
                [spoofmac] =>
            )

        [opt4] => Array
            (
                [descr] => NAS
                [if] => mvneta0.20
                [enable] =>
                [spoofmac] =>
                [ipaddr] => 10.168.20.1
                [subnet] => 24
            )

        [opt5] => Array
            (
                [descr] => VPN
                [if] => mvneta0.30
                [enable] =>
                [ipaddr] => 10.168.30.1
                [subnet] => 24
                [spoofmac] =>
            )

        [opt6] => Array
            (
                [descr] => GUEST
                [if] => mvneta0.40
                [enable] =>
                [ipaddr] => 172.16.40.1
                [subnet] => 24
                [spoofmac] =>
            )

    )

[staticroutes] =>
[dhcpd] => Array
    (
        [lan] => Array
            (
                [enable] =>
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 10.168.1.1
                        [to] => 10.168.1.254
                    )

                [dhcpleaseinlocaltime] =>
                [failover_peerip] =>
                [defaultleasetime] =>
                [maxleasetime] =>
                [netmask] =>
                [gateway] =>
                [domain] =>
                [domainsearchlist] =>
                [ddnsdomain] =>
                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                [ddnsdomainsecondary] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm] => hmac-md5
                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                [mac_allow] =>
                [mac_deny] =>
                [ddnsclientupdates] => allow
                [tftp] =>
                [ldap] =>
                [nextserver] =>
                [filename] =>
                [filename32] =>
                [filename64] =>
                [rootpath] =>
                [numberoptions] =>
            )

        [opt2] => Array
            (
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 10.168.5.1
                        [to] => 10.168.5.9
                    )

                [enable] =>
                [failover_peerip] =>
                [defaultleasetime] =>
                [maxleasetime] =>
                [netmask] =>
                [gateway] =>
                [domain] =>
                [domainsearchlist] =>
                [ddnsdomain] =>
                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                [ddnsdomainsecondary] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm] => hmac-md5
                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                [mac_allow] =>
                [mac_deny] =>
                [ddnsclientupdates] => allow
                [tftp] =>
                [ldap] =>
                [nextserver] =>
                [filename] =>
                [filename32] =>
                [filename64] =>
                [rootpath] =>
                [numberoptions] =>
                [dhcpleaseinlocaltime] =>
                [staticmap] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [mac] => f0:d5:bf:7d:43:99
                                [cid] =>
                                [ipaddr] => 10.168.5.11
                                [hostname] =>
                                [descr] => Christoph Laptop - WLAN
                                [filename] =>
                                [rootpath] =>
                                [defaultleasetime] =>
                                [maxleasetime] =>
                                [gateway] =>
                                [domain] =>
                                [domainsearchlist] =>
                                [ddnsdomain] =>
                                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                                [tftp] =>
                                [ldap] =>
                            )

                    )

            )

        [opt3] => Array
            (
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 10.168.10.11
                        [to] => 10.168.10.99
                    )

                [enable] =>
                [failover_peerip] =>
                [defaultleasetime] =>
                [maxleasetime] =>
                [netmask] =>
                [gateway] =>
                [domain] =>
                [domainsearchlist] =>
                [ddnsdomain] =>
                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                [ddnsdomainsecondary] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm] => hmac-md5
                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                [mac_allow] =>
                [mac_deny] =>
                [ddnsclientupdates] => allow
                [tftp] =>
                [ldap] =>
                [nextserver] =>
                [filename] =>
                [filename32] =>
                [filename64] =>
                [rootpath] =>
                [numberoptions] =>
                [dhcpleaseinlocaltime] =>
                [staticmap] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [mac] => 5c:f3:70:58:ec:c9
                                [cid] =>
                                [ipaddr] => 10.168.10.101
                                [hostname] =>
                                [descr] => Scanner (Brother)
                                [filename] =>
                                [rootpath] =>
                                [defaultleasetime] =>
                                [maxleasetime] =>
                                [gateway] =>
                                [domain] =>
                                [domainsearchlist] =>
                                [ddnsdomain] =>
                                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                                [tftp] =>
                                [ldap] =>
                            )

                    )

            )

        [opt4] => Array
            (
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 10.168.20.11
                        [to] => 10.168.20.99
                    )

                [enable] =>
                [failover_peerip] =>
                [defaultleasetime] =>
                [maxleasetime] =>
                [netmask] =>
                [gateway] =>
                [domain] =>
                [domainsearchlist] =>
                [ddnsdomain] =>
                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                [ddnsdomainsecondary] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm] => hmac-md5
                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                [mac_allow] =>
                [mac_deny] =>
                [ddnsclientupdates] => allow
                [tftp] =>
                [ldap] =>
                [nextserver] =>
                [filename] =>
                [filename32] =>
                [filename64] =>
                [rootpath] =>
                [numberoptions] =>
                [dhcpleaseinlocaltime] =>
                [staticmap] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [mac] => 00:11:32:5e:eb:41
                                [cid] =>
                                [ipaddr] => 10.168.20.100
                                [hostname] =>
                                [descr] => NAS
                                [filename] =>
                                [rootpath] =>
                                [defaultleasetime] =>
                                [maxleasetime] =>
                                [gateway] =>
                                [domain] =>
                                [domainsearchlist] =>
                                [ddnsdomain] =>
                                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                                [tftp] =>
                                [ldap] =>
                            )

                    )

            )

        [opt5] => Array
            (
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 10.168.30.11
                        [to] => 10.168.30.99
                    )

                [enable] =>
                [failover_peerip] =>
                [defaultleasetime] =>
                [maxleasetime] =>
                [netmask] =>
                [gateway] =>
                [domain] =>
                [domainsearchlist] =>
                [ddnsdomain] =>
                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                [ddnsdomainsecondary] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm] => hmac-md5
                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                [mac_allow] =>
                [mac_deny] =>
                [ddnsclientupdates] => allow
                [tftp] =>
                [ldap] =>
                [nextserver] =>
                [filename] =>
                [filename32] =>
                [filename64] =>
                [rootpath] =>
                [numberoptions] =>
                [dhcpleaseinlocaltime] =>
            )

        [opt6] => Array
            (
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 172.16.40.11
                        [to] => 172.16.40.99
                    )

                [enable] =>
                [failover_peerip] =>
                [defaultleasetime] =>
                [maxleasetime] =>
                [netmask] =>
                [gateway] =>
                [domain] =>
                [domainsearchlist] =>
                [ddnsdomain] =>
                [ddnsdomainprimary] =>
                [ddnsdomainsecondary] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyname] =>
                [ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm] => hmac-md5
                [ddnsdomainkey] =>
                [mac_allow] =>
                [mac_deny] =>
                [ddnsclientupdates] => allow
                [tftp] =>
                [ldap] =>
                [nextserver] =>
                [filename] =>
                [filename32] =>
                [filename64] =>
                [rootpath] =>
                [numberoptions] =>
                [dhcpleaseinlocaltime] =>
            )

    )

[dhcpdv6] => Array
    (
        [lan] => Array
            (
                [enable] =>
                [range] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => ::1000
                        [to] => ::2000
                    )

                [ramode] => assist
                [rapriority] => medium
            )

    )

[snmpd] => Array
    (
        [syslocation] =>
        [syscontact] =>
        [rocommunity] => public
    )

[diag] => Array
    (
        [ipv6nat] => Array
            (
                [ipaddr] =>
            )

    )

[syslog] => Array
    (
        [filterdescriptions] => 1
    )

[nat] => Array
    (
        [outbound] => Array
            (
                [mode] => automatic
            )

    )

[filter] => Array
    (
        [rule] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => pass
                        [ipprotocol] => inet
                        [descr] => Default allow LAN to any rule
                        [interface] => lan
                        [tracker] => 0100000101
                        [source] => Array
                            (
                                [network] => lan
                            )

                        [destination] => Array
                            (
                                [any] =>
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => pass
                        [ipprotocol] => inet6
                        [descr] => Default allow LAN IPv6 to any rule
                        [interface] => lan
                        [tracker] => 0100000102
                        [source] => Array
                            (
                                [network] => lan
                            )

                        [destination] => Array
                            (
                                [any] =>
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] =>
                        [tracker] => 1630477503
                        [type] => pass
                        [interface] => enc0
                        [ipprotocol] => inet
                        [tag] =>
                        [tagged] =>
                        [max] =>
                        [max-src-nodes] =>
                        [max-src-conn] =>
                        [max-src-states] =>
                        [statetimeout] =>
                        [statetype] => keep state
                        [os] =>
                        [source] => Array
                            (
                                [any] =>
                            )

                        [destination] => Array
                            (
                                [any] =>
                            )

                        [descr] =>
                        [updated] => Array
                            (
                                [time] => 1630477503
                                [username] => admin@10.168.5.11 (Local Datab                                                                                                                                                             ase)
                            )

                        [created] => Array
                            (
                                [time] => 1630477503
                                [username] => admin@10.168.5.11 (Local Datab                                                                                                                                                             ase)
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] =>
                        [tracker] => 1612988883
                        [type] => pass
                        [interface] => opt2
                        [ipprotocol] => inet
                        [tag] =>
                        [tagged] =>
                        [max] =>
                        [max-src-nodes] =>
                        [max-src-conn] =>
                        [max-src-states] =>
                        [statetimeout] =>
                        [statetype] => keep state
                        [os] =>
                        [source] => Array
                            (
                                [any] =>
                            )

                        [destination] => Array
                            (
                                [any] =>
                            )

                        [descr] => Allow all to all
                        [updated] => Array
                            (
                                [time] => 1612988883
                                [username] => admin@192.168.1.106 (Local Dat                                                                                                                                                             abase)
                            )

                        [created] => Array
                            (
                                [time] => 1612988883
                                [username] => admin@192.168.1.106 (Local Dat                                                                                                                                                             abase)
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] =>
                        [tracker] => 1613586931
                        [type] => pass
                        [interface] => opt3
                        [ipprotocol] => inet
                        [tag] =>
                        [tagged] =>
                        [max] =>
                        [max-src-nodes] =>
                        [max-src-conn] =>
                        [max-src-states] =>
                        [statetimeout] =>
                        [statetype] => keep state
                        [os] =>
                        [source] => Array
                            (
                                [address] => 10.168.10.101
                            )

                        [destination] => Array
                            (
                                [network] => opt4
                            )

                        [descr] => Allow scanner to NAS
                        [updated] => Array
                            (
                                [time] => 1613586931
                                [username] => admin@10.168.5.4 (Local Databa                                                                                                                                                             se)
                            )

                        [created] => Array
                            (
                                [time] => 1613586931
                                [username] => admin@10.168.5.4 (Local Databa                                                                                                                                                             se)
                            )

                    )
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the router configuration.

Comment: Please edit the question with the text version of the configuration. Simply list out the configuration, copy it, and paste it in and use the Preformatted-text feature.

Comment: That is not the text configuration. Go into the [shell](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/development/php-shell.html) and list it out. It will be a rather large amount of text

Comment: I don't know what is meant!?

Comment: Follow the link in my last comment. It explains how to list out the configuration.

Comment: Now it is over the limit of 30.000 characters.

Comment: You can remove a bunch of stuff from the question, and you can get rid of some irrelevant stuff from the configuration. Keep most of the configuration because there are thing that you may not think are relevant, but they really are.

Comment: There is a lot of the configuration missing. At the beginning because putty is limited and at the end because this forum is limited. I could abuse answers to provide the rest of it.

Comment: Please don't do that. It makes it impossible to read and answers are not meant to be used to provide additional information on the question.

Comment: Well, then I cannot provide the config.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What is meant by ID and shared secret?

The ID is whatever the peer uses to identify itself.  It could be a hostname, address, certificate, *etc*.

A shared secret is essentially a password -- something that only the peers know and can use to verify identity, or to encrypt data.